# How do I change the email address used for Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

My email address I use for the Play Store will be invalid soon, so I need to change it. However I don't want to make a new account because I want to keep all my apps. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to [add an alternate email](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/176347?hl=en) to your Google account. Afterwards, you can sign in with any of your alternate email addresses, using the same password for your main address.

Once your current email is invalidated, you should also be able to [remove that address](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/76143?hl=en) from your Google account and continue using your alternate email as the primary login.

Since the Google account stays the same, all of your apps will remain on your account.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't add an alternate email to my Google account, it says "this setting can't be changed".

Answer (score 0):

Open play store .. slide menu from left side and select email which you wants to use with playstore. But first add that email in gmail setting .

Answer (score -2):

Go to Settings -> Accounts -> Add new email there

Then open Play Store, open side menu and select that account.

Comment: `I want to keep all my apps` -- they won't be kept in the new account under Play Store, but only in the device (OP didn't make sure here). You'll have to manually visit every apps page in Store to add I guess.

Comment: @Firelord: I want to save my account, yes.